# Botón no envia los datos correctamente PHP

Tags: php

tengo intención de enviar los datos de un formulario, tengo un type submit con un name y su id y value, pero resulta que cuando le doy a Enviar y no entra dentro porque no sé que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias por su ayuda de ante mano.

**PHP**

```
echo "<form id='form_pieles' name='form_pieles' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>";
echo "<input type='submit'  id='btn_guardar_datos_treballador_tre' name='btn_guardar_datos_treballador_tre' value='Guardar'></input>";
echo "<input type='button'  id='btn_cancelar_datos_treballador' onclick='cancel();' name='btn_cancelar_datos_treballador' value='Cancelar'></input>";
echo "</form>";
```

include 'section_form_pieles.php';

**FICHERO 2 PHP**

```
  if (isset($_POST['btn_guardar_datos_treballador_tre'])){
echo "Entro"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si no he entendido mal lo que necesitas es que te muestre el echo una vez le des al botón de "submit", te recomiendo deberías usar un lenguaje para entornos de cliente para hacer este tipo de cosas (por ejemplo JS), podrías poner un `addEventListener()` en el botón y cuando le des haces que te inserte en la vista con un `innerHTML` (por ejemplo) o hacerlo de la manera que quieras.

PHP es un lenguaje pensado para servidor, mi recomendación es que no lo intentes usar para estas cosas.

Si por alguna razón si o si quieres que te haga el print de lo que tienes en ese documento de PHP tienes la opción de usar Ajax, pero creo que para lo que nos muestras en la pregunta  con la primera idea sería suficiente.

Y si no quieres usar JS se me ocurre que puedes imprimir el contenido de una `$_SESSION[]` o `$_COOKIE[]` en la vista definiendo lo que quieres imprimir en el controlador de el que vienes pero no te serviría de nada el formulario, al final hagas lo que hagas necesitarás de un lenguaje para cliente.

Espero que te pueda haber ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

@Luis el problema es que si lo quieres mandar a otro archivo por lo que veo... necesitas un action:

**PHP**

```
echo "<form id='form_pieles' name='form_pieles' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8' action='fichero2.php'>";
echo "<input type='submit'  id='btn_guardar_datos_treballador_tre' 
name='btn_guardar_datos_treballador_tre' value='Guardar'></input>";
echo "<input type='button'  id='btn_cancelar_datos_treballador' 
onclick='cancel();' name='btn_cancelar_datos_treballador' value='Cancelar'> 
</input>";
echo "</form>";
```

En el fichero2.php lo tienes correcto.

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_guardar_datos_treballador_tre'])){
 echo "Entro"
}
```

El action en un formulario es para decirle donde tiene que ir los datos, si no te hace un post en el mismo archivo donde esta el formulario.

Comment: Pero yo no quiero ir al fichero2. el fichero 2 solo me hara un insert realmente yo quiero que al darle a ese boton con el include me genere el echo entro